# Combining rows where dublicates are found

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an SQL query that will combine rows where a row sharing an ID is found, but print normally if now. I have a Computer and Harddisk database. The Computer DB has a Id and the Harddisk DB har a Id and a ComputerId for the associated computer. Some computers have more harddisks so I'd like to combine these into the same column.

I've attached a image below explaining the two tables and the desired output: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbht3.png)

My current query reads:
$queryHDDS = "SELECT *,CONCAT(ComputerId) FROM HardDisk GROUP BY Id";

Trouble is it is no combining two harddisks that are associated by a shared ComputerId

Hope someone is able to help me out with this!

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and add what you have so far (hint join)

Answer (score 0):

you could try using group_concat

```
    select Computer.ID, group_concat(harddisk.id)
    from Computer 
    inner join harddisk on Computer.id = harddisk.computerID
    group by Computer.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempted the following query (yours modified a little to be functional):

    $join = "SELECT *, group_concat(HardDisk.Id)
    from Computer 
    inner join HardDisk on Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId
    group by Computer.Id";

It lists harddisk with computerId 1-10 but there's 2 harddisks that has computer Id 6 and it does not list and join those two together. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @Dlaurs20   .. i'm not in yout data  ..  i have checkd the img you posted and my query should work correcly  (using computer.id)  .. but what do you mean with  there's 2 harddisks that has computer Id 6 and it does not list and join those two together.??  ..  .. try add a poroper data sample as tabular text not as img

Comment: I have made a new question with the tables properly setup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941945/issue-concatenating-rows-with-duplicates hope you can help!