# Issue concatenating rows with duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have run into some issues trying to combine a row of variables where dublicates can be found.

Computers with Ids are saved in the Computer table:

```
| Computer.Id |
|-------------|
| 1           |
| 2           |
| 3           |
| 4           |
| 5           |
| 6           |
| 7           |
| 8           |
| 9           |
```

Harddrive are saved in a HardDisk table with a HardDisk Id exclusive to the harddrive and a ComputerId linked to the Id in the Computer table

```
| Harddisk.ComputerId | Harddisk.Id |
|---------------------|-------------|
| 1                   | 1           |
| 2                   | 2           |
| 3                   | 3           |
| 4                   | 4           |
| 5                   | 5           |
| 6                   | 6           |
| 6                   | 7           |
| 7                   | 8           |
| 8                   | 9           |
| 9                   | 10          |
```

The output I am looking to achieve is:

```
| Harddisk.ComputerId | Harddisk.Id |
|---------------------|-------------|
| 1                   | 1           |
| 2                   | 2           |
| 3                   | 3           |
| 4                   | 4           |
| 5                   | 5           |
| 6                   | 6,7         |
| 7                   | 8           |
| 8                   | 9           |
| 9                   | 10          |
```

The output I'm currently getting is:

```
| Harddisk.ComputerId | Harddisk.Id |
|---------------------|-------------|
| 1                   | 1           |
| 2                   | 2           |
| 3                   | 3           |
| 4                   | 4           |
| 5                   | 5           |
| 6                   | 6           |
| 7                   | 8           |
| 8                   | 9           |
| 9                   | 10          |
```

Notice how Harddisk 7 which is the disk that shares Computer 6 is gone.

My current query looks like the following, courtesy of scaisEdge:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(HardDisk.Id)
from Computer
inner join HardDisk on Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId
group by Computer.Id
```

I hope someone is able to help me out!

Comment: Why is `ComputerId=10` missing from your expected results?

Comment: In the sample data I see harddisk id=6 installed into two computers id=6 and 7.

Comment: @forpas I had a slight formatting error in the second table. Solved now! There is only 9 computers but 10 disks

Comment: @Akina There was a small error in the table. Hardisk 6 and 7 are installed in Computer 6. My apologies.

Comment: Anytime you use `*` in conjunction with an aggregate function, you can be confident that things are going to go very awry. That said, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Your query works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/939539/1

Comment: @forpas I was just about to post an SQL fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/109649/2

Comment: @Strawberry changing the * to desired data (ComputerId, Product, Serial, Gigabytes) does not change the outcome unfortunately. We would like to keep things strictly SQL/PHP if possible

Comment: @Dlaurs20 There has to more going on here that's causing an issue.  With just the data/query you show everything is working correctly.

Comment: @Dlaurs20 your application code is in php then - this is what Straberry suggested, handle display requirements there, not in your sql logic

Comment: That's great. PHP *is* application code

Comment: @forpas You and I have markedly different understandings of the term 'fine'

Comment: @Strawberry In the SQL query, the `GROUP_CONCAT` row shows the correct data when pared with the `ComputerID` row.  Seems "fine" to me...

Comment: @Strawberry this is also 'fine'.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Strange then that 8+ would reject this query outright (without some nefarious tweaking under the hood) - but I know you know this already

Comment: @Strawberry MySQL 8 rejects this query?  What do you mean?  What error does it give?  I didn't know that MySQL 8 made changes like that, I personally use MariaDB.

Comment: @Strawberry MariaDB 10.5 runs the query just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bf2589f7292df6d390b0671f17aace54  I'll test MySQL 8 and see if I can figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: @Strawberry Huh... guess you're right.  (Tested at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf2589f7292df6d390b0671f17aace54 ) I didn't realize MySQL 8 had changes like that... `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'HardDisk.Id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.  Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use * because this  produce an a wrong aggregation in mysql for version < 5.7

try use explicit column's name in select

```
SELECT computer.ID, group_concat(HardDisk.Id) my_disk
from Computer
inner join HardDisk on Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId
group by Computer.Id
```

if you need more column's not related  to  the same aggreagtion level you need  a join

In mysql version < 5.7 if some columns mentioned  in select clause are not mentioned properly in group by the aggregation function return the first occurrence of the select and not the correct aggreagted  result

try add

```
 echo  $row['my_disk];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "produce an a wrong aggregation"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat  answer  updated  with a brief explanation for your comment

Comment: SELECT ComputerId, group_concat(HardDisk.Id)
    from Computer
    inner join HardDisk on Computer.Id = HardDisk.ComputerId
    group by Computer.Id

I tried this code. I had to remove the . between Computer and Id in the beginning for it to work, but it simply lists HardDisk 1-9 skipping the computer with two harddisks

Comment: @Dlaurs20   . i have build  the same  situation  on my  pc and work fine  .. the check better  and try using computer.ID instead of ComputerID .. (as in my code)

Comment: @Dlaurs20 How are you testing/running this query?  There's got to be other data/rows in your table that is messing this query up.  This query works fine with the [sample] data you've provided.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It is running on the database that contains all the related information. But that should not affect the Ids queried? 

I query the DB with the query above (changed exactly to Scais version now) and do the following:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryHDDSResult)) {
            echo $row['Id'];
        }

Comment: could be you need  a proper alias for te result  .. answer  updated  adding the column alias and a suggestion for the echo

Comment: @Dlaurs20 And what you do see echoed?  That `$row['Id']` is your `Computer.Id`.  Try to `var_dump($row)` and see what you get.  Or try running this directly in MySQL and not via PHP to see what you get.

Comment: When I var_dump($row) I do get string(3) "6,7", wonder why it doesn't show when I echo it out. Echoed I just see 123456789

Comment: @Dlaurs20   . try add the alias as in my suggestion and echo the alias column name  .. (eventually add  break line <br/>

Comment: @Dlaurs20 Look at the keys of the array in the `var_dump`.  `Id` is the `Computer.Id`.  The other is probably named _literally_ `group_concat(HardDisk.Id)`.  You'll need to edit the query to add an alias.  `group_concat(HardDisk.Id) AS disks`.  Then you can use `$row['disks']`.

Comment: There we go! Success! It is now echoing: 123456,78910 Thank you so much everyone :D